# Ionic Push Plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

Can anybody help me in understanding the ionic push plugin, I have followed the documentation but it does not have much information.

I am struggling to perform some basic setups like.

- Push notification icon
- Background push notification to a page in app
- On demand prompt to user for enable/disable push notification and deviceToken management

Answer (score 0):

Quickest solution for me was to implement the FCM plugin. I also looked over the docs and the FCM module just made it very simple and easy to understand.

fcm module gets the token, then registers this on my server. From there I have the npm firebase module to send push notifications to users.

Comment: Did you mean FCM plugin for ionic? Does it provide enough control to change things programetically. We are using FCM and APNS for android and ios respectively for push notification.